# what features are extracted or what parameters are used to distinguish a user in ASR system using MFCC?

Tags: matlab, mfcc

What are the features that the MFCC extracts from speakers during testing phase?

I know the method how to compute mfcc steps are:

- I split the signal in small frames with 10 to 30ms
- Apply a windowing function (humming [sic] is recommended for sound applications)
- Compute the fourier transform of the signal,
- With DFT, to compute Mel Frequecy Cepstral Coefficients :

  - Get power spectrum: |DFT|^2
  - Compute a triangular bank filter to transform hz scale into mel scale
  - Get log spectrum
  - Apply discrete cos transform

By doing these I get coefficients. But I want to know how these coefficients are related to users voice. What are these coefficients representing?

Comment: Could you please narrow down your question by explaining what you already understand about MFCC, and where your problem is. Have you looked at any relevant documentation? Stack Overflow users cannot write general tutorials to explain "grasp the concept of mfcc" - and even if we did it might have the same problems for you as any other reference that you have read.

Comment: ok ,i know the method how to compute mfcc steps are :First, i split the signal in small frames with 10 to 30ms, apply a windowing function (humming is recommended for sound applications), and compute the fourier transform of the signal. With DFT, to compute Mel Frequecy Cepstral Coefficients :

Get power spectrum: |DFT|^2
Compute a triangular bank filter to transform hz scale into mel scale
Get log spectrum
Apply discrete cos transform by doing these i get coefficients.But i want to know how these coefficients are related to users voice.what are these coefficients representing.

Answer (score 1):

MFCC gives you a time series of power-by-frequency in an audio source. The adjustments from a "raw" DFT-based power series serves two basic purposes:

1) Changing from the linear scale (of frequency and power) you get from raw DFT into log scale. This aligns with how human (and most animal) auditory systems perceive sounds.

2) Compressing a large amount of data into a smaller feature set which is still good enough to distinguish important perceptual differences between the sounds. This compression is especially useful at high frequencies - for most speech/ASR applications, detecting the difference between power levels at 1001 Hz and 999 Hz has very little value.

> What are these coefficients representing?

Frequency content of the audio source, same as raw DFT, but adjusted to match known properties of human perception. These adjustments make theoretical sense when analysing spoken communication, where our voices and hearing have co-evolved.